# Fetching DB Rows to fill Boxes

Tags: php, html, css

I want to fetch data from DB , But i want

fill them in boxes and to make other un-filled

boxes with another styling just like that :

```
########################## ##########################    
########## BOX ########### ########## BOX ###########
########################## ##########################

########################## ##########################    
########## BOX ########### ########## EMPTY #########
########################## ##########################
```

**EXPLAINATION**

I'm Using Laravel PHP Framework to develop my App ,

And in my design , I want to Fill the Boxes Just as i showed up there ,

I have a DB Table now called 'Courses' and i want to fetch the Latest Courses ,

This is Image from my design ,

**DON'T CARE FOR LANG.**

[image]

Comment: Why -1 ??
I just want an idea , I will code it .

Comment: `What have you tried?`

Comment: show us some code. What have you tried?

Comment: Please re-word the question, it's not clear what you are doing.

Comment: Ok Sorry Guys I'll re-write it now

Comment: Updated ! It's Edited with Details Now !

Comment: OK, so when you `loop` through the courses to output them, you need to add a different class to each box you want a different colour. so
`<div class="box orange-box">` for example, `box` would contain the general size styling, so you don't need to repeat that, and `orange-box` would contain the `background-color`

Comment: how does your current PHP Code looks like?

Comment: @NickR
You didn't get it , The Colors of the boxes is Easy ,
Now I have 4 Courses , I want to fetch them , And to fill the remaining 2 boxes with basic ( disabled ( grey ) ) Styling
If they are 5 , 1 will be grey etc...

Comment: It's very basic guys , Do you use Chrome ?
When you open New tab you get most frequent pages you open , If they are 4 , You will find the remaining 4 Blocks are colored in grey , 
In my case it will be data from DB

Comment: So then you need to change your loop, and on each iteration check if the data is not `null` then spit out the div with the coloured class. Otherwise if there isn't, echo out `<div class="disabled"></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of my head you could do this like so.

Have not tested this!

Also replace count function with native laravel function to count recursive object returned from your database driver.

This will add empty boxes if theres 3 records it will add 0 empty boxes, if theres 4 records it will add 2 empty boxes and so on.

```
$records = array(
    0 => 'box0',
    1 => 'box1',
    2 => 'box2',
    3 => 'box3',
    4 => 'box4',
);

$records_count = count($records);

$filler  = 0;


if($records_count % 3 == 1)
{
    // we have 2 boxes to fill with gray
    $filler = 2;
}
elseif($records_count % 3 == 2)
{
    // we have 1 box to fill with gray
    $filler = 1;
}

foreach($records as $record)
{
    echo '<div class="box full">myboxfull</div>';
}

if(!empty($filler))
{
    for($i = $filler; $i > 0; $i--)
    {
        echo '<div class="box empty">myemptybox</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep That's What i want :)
I'll edit it and use it , Thanks Very Much !!

Comment: @KhalidKhalil glad you can use this, good luck.